# Find all integer solutions of $n = 1 + a + b + c$, with $a,b,c$ distinct divisors of $n$, and prove there are no more solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question derived from the [17 camels problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/17-animal_inheritance_puzzle). I have been asked to find every integer $n$ satisfying
$$
n = 1+a+b+c,
$$
where $a, b, c$ are distinct divisors of $n$ greater than one. By brute-forcing I got the answer $n\in\{12,18,20,24,42\}$:
\begin{align}
12 &= 1+2+3+6, \\
18 &= 1+2+6+9, \\
20 &= 1+4+5+10, \\
24 &= 1+3+8+12, \\
42 &= 1+6+14+21.
\end{align}
Now I have to prove these are the only solutions. How can I aproach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loss of generality let $1<c<b<a$. Dividing by $n$ gives
$$1=\frac1{a'}+\frac1{b'}+\frac1{c'}+\frac1n$$
where $a'=\frac na$ is a natural number, similarly for $b'$ and $c'$, and $1<a'<b'<c'<n$.

In particular a triple $(a'+k,b'+l,c'+m)$ cannot lead to a solution for any nonnegative integers $k,l,m$ if $1-\frac1{a'}-\frac1{b'}-\frac1{c'}\ge\frac1{c'}$ as this would lead to $c\le1$. $(4,5,6)$ and $(3,4,6)$ fail this test and $(3,4,5)$ does not lead to a solution, so any solution must have $a'=2$. $(2,6,7)$ fails the test, so $b'\in\{3,4,5\}$; $(2,3,12),(2,4,8),(2,5,7)$ also fail the test, so ultimately we have a finite number of cases to check:
$$(2,3,c),4\le c\le 11$$
$$(2,4,5),(2,4,6),(2,4,7),(2,5,6)$$
$(2,3,4)$ to $(2,3,6)$ would lead to negative or undefined $n$, so they are rejected. $(2,3,7)$ gives $n=42$ ($1=\frac12+\frac13+\frac17+\frac1{42}$). $(2,3,8)$ gives $n=24$, $(2,3,9)$ gives $n=18$, $(2,4,5)$ gives $n=20$, $(2,4,6)$ gives $n=12$ and the other cases do not lead to solutions. This settles the matter.

Comment: (+1)I have seen a similar idea in some IMOSL too :)

Comment: Nice and elegant. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C$ be integers such that $a=n/A$, $b=n/B$, $c=n/C$. We may and do sort these different numbers so that
$$
A< B< C\ .
$$
Let us observe that the smallest number $A$ among them has to be $2$, else $A\ge 3$, $B\ge 4$, $C\ge 5$, and we obtain a contradiction from $n=1+a+b+c=\frac nA+\frac nB+\frac nC<\frac n3+\frac n4+\frac n5=n\cdot \frac{47}{60}$. Now set $A=2$. Then we have
$$
\frac n2 =1+\frac nB+\frac nC\ .
$$
The last number is between $\frac nB+\frac nC$ and $\frac nB+2\frac nC$.
It remains to collect first all $B,C$ with $2<B<C$ that satisfy
$$
\frac 1B+\frac 1C <\frac 12<\frac 1B+\frac 2C\ ,
$$
Then check if there is any solution for the corresponding triple $(A,B,C)$.
We have $\frac 2C<\frac 1B+\frac 1C<\frac 12$, so $C>4$, so $C$ is among $5,6,7,8,\dots$. This allows to work on the other side, $\frac 1B>\frac 12-\frac 2C\ge \frac 12-\frac 25$, which gives $B<10$, so for $B$ we have to check the values $3,4,5,6,7,8,9$. All estimations above were rough, but the cases to be checked are no so many, so let us cover them one by one.

- $(A,B)=(2,3)$ leads to $n=1+\frac n2+\frac n3+\frac nC$, i.e. $\frac n6=1+\frac nC$, i.e. $\left(\frac 16-\frac 1C\right)n=1$. The fraction $\left(\frac 16-\frac 1C\right)=\frac{C-6}{6C}$ must be simplified, so that the numerator becomes one, else we do not have a solution. For the values of $C$ such that $C-6$ divides $6$ we immediately get solutions:
  $$
  \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|l|}
  \hline
  A & B & C & (C-6)/(6C) & n & n=1+a+b+c\\\hline
  2 & 3 & 7 & 1/42 & 42 & 42 = 1 + 21 + 14 + 7 \\\hline
  2 & 3 & 8 & 2/48=1/24 & 24 & 24 = 1 + 12 + 8 + 3 \\\hline
  2 & 3 & 9 & 3/54=1/18 & 18 & 18 = 1 + 9 + 6 + 2 \\\hline
  2 & 3 & 12 & 6/72=1/12 & 12 & 12 = 1 + 6 + 4 + 1 \\\hline
  \end{array}
  $$
  Assume now that $C-6$ does not divide $6$. It may be that a simplification with $2$ or $3$ occurs, but the remained part $d\in \{2,3,6\}$ which is relatively prime to $C$ must divide $C$. But from $d$ divides $6$, $d$ divides $C$, and $d$ does not divide $C-6$ we obtain a contradiction. So there is no other solution.
- $(A,B)=(2,4)$ leads to $n=1+\frac n2+\frac n4+\frac nC$, i.e. $\frac n4=1+\frac nC$, i.e. $\left(\frac 14-\frac 1C\right)n=1$. The fraction $\left(\frac 14-\frac 1C\right)=\frac{C-4}{4C}$ must be simplified, so that the numerator becomes one, else we do not have a solution. For the values of $C$ such that $C-4$ divides $4$ we immediately get solutions:
  $$
  \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|l|}
  \hline
  A & B & C & (C-4)/(4C) & n & n=1+a+b+c\\\hline
  2 & 4 & 5 & 1/20 & 20 & 20 = 1 + 10 + 5 + 4 \\\hline
  2 & 4 & 6 & 2/24=1/12 & 12 & 12 = 1 + 6 + 3 + 2 \\\hline
  2 & 4 & 8 & 4/32=1/8 & 8 & 8 = 1 + 4 + 2 + 1 \\\hline
  \end{array}
  $$
  For other $C<8$ simplification does not occur,
  for values $C>8$ the fraction $(C-4)/(4C)$ is bigger than $8$, $n$ smaller,
  so $n/C$ is no longer an integer. No solution.
- $(A,B)=(2,5)$ leads to $n=1+\frac n2+\frac n5+\frac nC$, i.e. $\frac {3n}{10}=1+\frac nC$, i.e. $\left(\frac 3{10}-\frac 1C\right)n=1$. The fraction $\left(\frac 3{10}-\frac 1C\right)=\frac{3C-10}{10C}$ must be simplified, so that the numerator becomes one, else we do not have a solution. As a function of $C$, the fraction is increasing. For $C=6,7,8,9$ there is no full denominator simplification, for $C=10$ (or bigger) we obtain $\frac{3}{10}-\frac 1{10}=\frac 15$, so $n$ is $5$ (or smaller), so there is no solution.
- $(A,B)=(2,6)$ leads to $n=1+\frac n2+\frac n6+\frac nC$, i.e. $\frac n3=1+\frac nC$, i.e. $\left(\frac 13-\frac 1C\right)n=1$. The fraction $\left(\frac 13-\frac 1C\right)=\frac{C-3}{3C}$ must be simplified, so that the numerator becomes one, else we do not have a solution. As a function of $C$, the fraction is increasing. For $C=7,8$ there is no full denominator simplification, for $C=9$ (or bigger) we obtain $\frac 13-\frac 19=\frac 29$, so $n\le \frac 92<C$ , so there is no solution.

The remained cases ($B=7,8,9$) are similar, and lead to no solution.

Comment: Oh, there is already a short solution that does the job... Shall i delete the present very pedestrian approach?!

Answer (score 0):

**If $n=1+a+b+c$ with $a,b,c$ distinct divisors of $n$ and $a\lt b\lt c$ then  $c=\dfrac n2$**.

In fact, if $c\le\lfloor\dfrac n3\rfloor$ we have $$n\le 1+\lfloor\dfrac n5\rfloor+\lfloor\dfrac n4\rfloor+\lfloor\dfrac n3\rfloor\le1+n\left(\dfrac15+\dfrac14+\dfrac13\right)$$ which implies $\dfrac{13 n}{60}\le1$ so $n\le 4$ which can be discarded straightforward. **A consequence is that $n$ should be even**.

So we have to find even $n\gt42$ such that $$n=1+a+b+\frac n2\iff \frac n2=1+a+b$$
If $n$ is divisible by $3$ and $4$ we have
$\dfrac n2=1+\dfrac n4+\dfrac n3$ which give $LHS\lt RHS$ so we must have $\dfrac n2\le1+\dfrac n5+\dfrac n4$ which give $n\le 20\lt42$. If $n$ is not divisible by $3$ and $4$ we would have as possibility $$\dfrac n2\le1+\lfloor\dfrac n6\rfloor+\lfloor\dfrac n5\rfloor\le1+n\left(\dfrac{11}{30}\right)$$ and still we get impossibility. It follows that for other smaller possible divisors we are not  solutions.

We are done: $n\in\{12,18,20,24,42\}$ is the whole set of solutions as the OP have supposed.